# EF extension AddIfNotExists local lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, extension-methods

I made an generic extension method to add new entities only if a specified key doesn’t exists.
This works for the data in the database, but I also want to check the Local values. Maybe it has been added and didn’t saved to the database yet.
I use the following code:

```
public static void AddIfNotExists<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifierexp, params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (set == null)
            throw new Exception("DbSet not assinged");
        if (entities == null)
            throw new Exception("Entities not assinged");

        var dbSet = set as DbSet<TEntity>;

        if (dbSet != null)
        {
            MemberExpression body = identifierexp.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (body == null)
            {
                UnaryExpression ubody = (UnaryExpression)identifierexp.Body;
                body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }


            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "X");
            Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, body.Member.Name);

            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                Expression target = Expression.Constant(entity.GetType().GetProperty(body.Member.Name).GetValue(entity).ToString());
                Expression containsMethod = Expression.Call(property, "Contains", null, target);
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lamba = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsMethod, parameter);

                var Exists = dbSet.SingleOrDefault(lamba);
                

                if (Exists == null)
                {
                    dbSet.Add(entity);
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

When I change it with the following code he can’t use `Lambda` on the local property. Because the is not a right overload. But as far as I can see the overload is the same.  What is the right way?

```
                var Exists = dbSet.Local.SingleOrDefault(lamba);
                if (Exists != null)
                    return;

                Exists = dbSet.SingleOrDefault(lamba);
                if (Exists != null)
                    return;

                dbSet.Add(entity);
```

And the error i'm getting:

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOrDefault' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: `Expression<Func<>>` is not the same as `Func<>`. If you look at Local it is taking a delegate (Func<>) not an expression tree (Expression<Func<>>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `dbSet.Local` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`. The LINQ extensions for `IEnumerable<T>` only accept delegates, not expressions representing those.

There are two ways to fix that:

1. Compile your lambda expression to a delegate by using the `Compile()` method, and use that for the local query.
   The resulting code should look like this:

   ```
   var Exists = dbSet.Local.SingleOrDefault(lamba.Compile());
   ```
2. Wrap the local collection in an `IQueryable<T>` implementation by invoking `AsQueryable()` on it.
   The resulting code should look like this:

   ```
   var Exists = dbSet.Local.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(lamba);
   ```